# Get only variable part of slug custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

On my homepage, I wrote a query to show all the elements in a taxonomy (jobpost_job_type)
I want to link them to the archive page, but adjust the url of the search so the right results are shown.

```
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false
);
$taxonomy = 'jobpost_job_type';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);
$terms_count = $terms->count;

?>
<div class="jobs__types--wrapper">
    <?php if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { ?>
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <a class="jobs__types--item" href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?><span> (<?php echo $term->count; ?>)</span></a>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <a class="jobs__types--item" href="">Spontaan solliciteren</a>
    <a class="jobs__types--item" href="">Werken bij ons</a>
    <a class="jobs__types--item" href="">Andere</a>
</div>
```

Now the url the link is going to is: https://ago.staging.dfib.net/vacatures-type/maintenance-engineering/
I want to change it to: https://ago.staging.dfib.net/vacatures/?search_keywords=&selected_jobtype=maintenance-engineering&selected_location=-1

How can I only get 'maintenance-engineer' from the slug and use in in the url I need?

Comment: What is `vacatures` and `vacatures-type` here?

Comment: Vacatures is the archive page for the jobs, vacature-type is the archive page for a particular job type, in this example the type is maintenance-engineering

Comment: `get_post_type_archive_link( 'jobs' );` will provide you the post type archive link and the `$term->slug` will provide you `maintenance-engineer`

Comment: This gave me a direction to rebuild the url I needed, thanks!